# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 11, **69a: $f$ continuous and increasing at every $a \in [0,1]$. Prove $f$ increasing on $[0,1]$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

> **69. A function $f$ is increasing at $a$ if there is some number $\delta>0$ such that
>
> $$f(x)>f(a) \text{ if } a<x<a+\delta$$
>
> and
>
> $$f(x)<f(a) \text{ if } a-\delta<x<a$$
>
> (a) Suppose that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and that $f$ is
> increasing at $a$ for every $a \in [0,1]$. Prove that $f$ is
> increasing on $[0,1]$. (First convince yourself that there is
> something to be proved.) Hint: For $0<b<1$, prove that the minimum of
> $f$ on $[b,1]$ must be at $b$.

As usual after writing my proof, it turned out longer than the solution manual proof. I am wondering if it is correct.

**My Proof**

Let $b \in [0,1]$.

Then $f$ is increasing at $b$.

In particular, $$\exists \epsilon>0\ \forall x\ x \in (b, b+\delta) \implies f(x)>f(b)$$

Let $c \geq b+\delta$.

Assume $f(c) \leq f(b)$.

Mean Value Theorem says

$$\exists d, d \in (c,b) \land f'(d) = \frac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}\leq 0$$

That is

$$\forall \epsilon>0\ \exists \delta>0\ \forall x, 0<|x-d|<\delta \implies f'(d)-\epsilon \leq \frac{f(x)-f(d)}{x-d} \leq f'(d)+\epsilon$$

In particular,

$$\exists x_1, x_1 \in (d, d+\delta) \land \frac{f(x_1)-f(d)}{x_1-d} \leq 0$$

$$\implies f(x_1) \leq f(d)$$

Therefore, $f$ not increasing at $d$. $\bot$.

Therefore,

$$\forall x, x \geq b+\delta \implies f(x) > f(b)$$

But since $f$ is increasing at $b$ it is also true that

$$\forall x, b<x<b+\delta \implies f(x)>f(b)$$

Therefore

$$\forall x, x>b \implies f(x)>f(b)$$

The minimum of $f$ on $[b,1]$ is therefore at $b$.

Since this reasoning was for any $b \in [0,1]$, we conclude that

$$\forall x\ \forall y, x \in [0,1] \land y \in [0,1] \land x<y \implies f(x)<f(y)$$

$\blacksquare$

**Here is the solution manual proof**

If the minimum of $f$ on $[b,1]$ occurred at some $c$ with $b<c \leq 1$, then $f$ would clearly not be increasing at $c$, since we would have $f(x) \geq f(c)$ for all $x<c$ sufficiently close to $c$.

Now if $0 \leq a<b<1$, then the minimum of $f$ on $[a,1]$ is $a$, so $f(a) \leq f(b)$.

To obtain strict inequality $f(a) < f(b)$, pick some $a'$ with $a<a'<b$ such that $f(a')>f(a)$ (this is possible since $f$ is increasing at $a$); then $f(a)<f(a')\leq f(b)$.

$\blacksquare$

I have this habit of writing proofs with mathematical symbols rather than giving an informal argument. Is this bad? Is the first proof worse than the second proof?

Comment: To respond to your final questions: Personally, I dislike proofs that are written entirely in symbols.  They may be logically correct, but they do not guide the reader through the thought processes in the construction.  The reader does not get the structure of the idea from symbols alone.

Comment: I have the same feeling, though when I am thinking about the problem, the logical structure helps me move from one step to the next. Perhaps the next step is to take the completed proof with mathematical symbols and try to write it in a more readable way with more english.

Comment: In your proof, why does the derivative exist?  There are increasing functions which do not have derivatives everywhere.

Comment: Why do you consider the second proof as an "informal argument" ?

Comment: @MichaelBurr In order to apply the Mean Value Theorem, I would need the additional assumption that $f$ is differentiable on $(b,1)$. I think your observation has invalidated my proof.

Comment: The second argument isn't more or less formal, but it doesn't write the statements in pure symbols.  Pure symbols are easy for computers to read, but can look like "alphabet soup" if given to a human.  While there is content there, it's not in a form that most people (including mathematicians) can process immediately.  I need to read it twice, once to read the symbols, second to process the meaning/content of the symbols.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe At some point after starting to study this book by Spivak, I took a course on first order logic. I just went back to the textbook and found this snippet: "We will use the dialect most common in mathematics, though we will also tell you about several other dialects along the way. FOL is used in different ways in different fields. In mathematics, it is used in an informal way quite extensively. The various connectives and quantifiers find their way into a great deal of mathematical discourse, both formal and informal, as in a classroom setting."

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I think my impression is that if you were to write a proof completely formally it would only have very precisely defined symbols and expressions. English isn't necessarily precise. On the other hand, 100% precision is unnecessary for a human to understand a proof. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using symbols like you did is fine when you are writing your own notes or a sketch of a proof to yourself, but when you want to present it to others, it's usually clearest if you write in full sentences and use the logical symbols very sparingly, if at all.

That said, I think the larger issue with your argument is that it assumes $f$ is differentiable, which is not one of the assumptions being made about $f$ in the statement of 69, part (a). The exercise is meant to increase understanding about the interplay of compactness and continuity, a challenge the proposed argument sidesteps with the extra assumption of differentiability.